# Wrapping boost::signal to C# delegates

Tags: c#, c++, boost, wrapper, swig

say I have an asynchronous library, written in native C++, with an interface similar to this:

```
class connection {
public:
    boost::signal< void() > sig_connection_made;
    boost::signal< void(const std::string&) > sig_error;

    void connect(const std::string& host, const std::string& port);
};
```

that I want to wrap in C#. Does anyone know of a way, using SWIG or something similar, that will allow me to bind the signals to C# delegates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass a delegate into c++ from C# using SWIG assign it to a function pointer and then call the function pointer and it will trigger the delegate.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a task for [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI).

Also see [Mixed Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0w2664k.aspx) and [Calling Native Functions from Managed Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235282.aspx).

Comment: Not as simple as I would have liked, but it never is :). I'll definitely look into it and see if I can write an intermediate wrapper in C++/CLI which does the necessary translation.

Comment: Indeed.  But this is one of .NET's biggest problems:  getting it to interface with everything else.  Good luck to you!